# How do I increase the number of MIDI through ports in ALSA?

Tags: linux, alsa, midi

ALSA always creates 1 MIDI through port. Since I work with Windows music applications via Wine, and because MIDI through ports are everything-proof, how can I increase the amount of MIDI through ports created by ALSA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ modinfo snd-seq-dummy
...
description:    ALSA sequencer MIDI-through client
...
parm:           ports:number of ports to be created (int)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding midi through ports:

1. Install missing alsa components:

   - `sudo apt-get install alsa-oss`
   - `sudo apt-get install` (alsa missing components if it nessessary)
2. run text editor as administrator:

   - `sudo kate`  (or sudo gedit or sudo somethingtexteditor)
3. In text editor type line:
   `options snd-seq-dummy ports=16`  (ports=as many as you want)
4. Save the text file to `/etc/modprobe.d/Nameyoulike.conf`
5. Close text editor
6. Reboot